# Hash has_key? syntax

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

I have three Hashes:

```
a = {key:"value"}
b = {"key"=>"value"}
c = {:key=>"value"}
```

And these results:

```
a.has_key?("key") # => false
b.has_key?("key") # => true
c.has_key?("key") # => false
```

My questions are:

- Why? What is this behavior?
- How can I get `a`, `b` and `c` to return `true` using the same syntax for all of them?

Comment: Note that `Hash#has_key?` [has been deprecated](https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5555#note-10) in favor of `Hash#key?`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are strings and there are symbols. A string is not a symbol.

These hashes contain a symbol as a key:

```
{key: "value"}
{:key => "value"}
```

This hash contains a string as a key:

```
{"key"=>"value"}
```

That's why your tests behave like they do.

Rails has a wrapper for Hash, called [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html). If you have one of those, you can access values by either strings or symbols. But for regular hashes, there's distinction.

```
require "active_support/core_ext"

h = {key: "value"}.with_indifferent_access

h.has_key?(:key) # => true
h.has_key?("key") # => true
```

Comment: Good enough! So the solution for my issue is `c.with_indifferent_access.has_key?("key")//true`

Comment: Note, though, that `.with_indifferent_access` call creates a new object.

Comment: `with_indifferent_access` always makes me itchy. It solves a problem, but I always feel like I should know exactly how my hashes keys are defined, and that they should always be either symbols or strings (or some predetermined object type), and not multiple types. As a result I don't use it but my coding partner does.

Comment: @theTinMan: I also don't use it. And my hashes have mostly symbol keys. Except when I'm parsing user input.

Answer (score 2):

If you observe while you assign the hashes, in IRB they're like this:

```
2.0.0p247 :014 > a = {key:"values"}
 => {:key=>"values"} 
2.0.0p247 :015 > b = {"key" => "values"}
 => {"key"=>"values"} 
2.0.0p247 :016 > c = {:key => "value"}
 => {:key=>"value"}
```

We can see that `a` and `c` are the same, other than the syntax used for assigning. The syntax used for `c` is I guess the old syntax.

```
a = {key:"values"}
```

is the syntax introduced in the latest Ruby version. In both hash `a` and `c`, the key is `a` symbol.

"[The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)" explains the difference between string and symbol,
whereas in hash `b` the key value is a string. Apparently its value is "key". The major difference is the value of key for hash `b` is mutable while it's not true in case of hash `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the symbol `:key` for hash `a` and `c`.

```
a = {key: "value"}
b = {"key" => "value"}
c = {:key => "value"}
a.has_key? :key # => true
b.has_key? :key # => false
c.has_key? :key # => true
```

`{key:"value"}` is equivalent to `{:key=>"value"}`.