# check a key is available in a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a partial named test in rails and I am sending some data in locals hash, I need to check if title exists in locals hash.

```
<%= render partial: "/test", :locals => {
        :title  => "sample title"
      } 
      %>
```

I tried with

```
locals.has_key? 'title',
```

But it is not working. Can any one help in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to check if title exists in locals hash.

Well, for that you have to do `local_assigns.has_key? :some_local`.

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key?(:some_local) %>
  <%= some code here %>
<% end %>
```

I didn't get the *documentation* from Rails guide, but I knew this feature, that's why I mentioned it here. But here are some discussions on [15700](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15700) and [18970](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18970) about `local_assigns` on guides.

Finally with the help of [@stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939644/check-a-key-is-available-in-a-hash-in-ruby/28939783#comment46139874_28939783) I found out the documentation of the method [`local_assigns`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html#method-i-local_assigns).

Comment: locals.has_key?(:description), I tried in this way Not working

Comment: It's already documented in the edge API: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html#method-i-local_assigns

Comment: @Stefan Thanks.. I searched to support my answer.. :) Didn't get it.

Comment: :locals => {
        :title  => {:subname => 'Raja'}
      } . How to check locals.title.subname is available or not?

Comment: @Raj Well.. suppose you have `h = {a: {b: 10}`, then `h[:a][:b]` will give you `10`. BTW, Did you try what I said  ? like `local_assigns.has_key?(:title)`

Comment: yeah.. it worked. Thanks you saved my time. but in the same scenario if i access nested hash its not working. can you please help in this?

Comment: You can ask a separate question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write **title** as `string`,not as `symbol`

```
<%= render partial: "/test", :locals => {"title"  => "sample title" } %>
```

Now `locals.has_key? "title"` will return `true`

For reference see this [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809920/hash-has-key-syntax)

Comment: is that possible to do with :title, instead of 'title' ?

Comment: @Raj No,a `key` in a `hash` should be **string** but not **symbol** OR you should use [**HashWithIndifferentAccess**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
<%= render '/test', title: 'sample title' %>
```

Within the locale you do this:

```
if defined?(title) 
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `'title'` and `:title` are separate keys. You can use `:title` or `'title'.to_sym` instead.